# Floor in a Sorted Array

Tags: java, binary-search

I have a sorted array `arr[]` of size `n` without duplicates, and given a value `x`. Floor of `x` is defined as the largest element K in `arr[]` such that K is smaller than or equal to `x`. Find the index of *K(0-based indexing)*.

**Input:**

```
n = 7
x = 0
arr[] = {1,2,8,10,11,12,19}
```

**Output:**

```
1
```

I have to solve it in *O(logn)*.
The code which I have below passes the test cases but it's showing time limit exceeded. What is wrong with this code?

```
static int findFloor(long arr[], int n, long x) {
    int low = 0;
    int high = n - 1;
    while (low <= high) {
        int mid = (low + high) / 2;
        if (arr[mid] > x) {
            if (mid != 0 && arr[mid - 1] < x) {
                return mid;
            } else {
                high = mid - 1;
            }
        } else if (arr[mid] < x) {
            low = mid + 1;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: `n=1, x=10, arr[]={10}` I think this one (and any similar case) will go for an infinite loop.

Comment: You don't do anything when arr[mid] == x. So you enter in infinite loop. In your else if condition change arr[mid] < x to arr[mid] <= x.

Comment: but my answer is comming wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your program will stuck in infinite for the case `arr[mid] == x` as you haven't handled this case. Also, I don't see this program work properly for other cases also.

For example, if I give `x=7`, this will return the index `2`, which is wrong. The correct index should be `1` as `x=7` is greater then `arr[1] == 2` and less than `arr[2] == 8`.

Also, your code will break if I give a input of greater than the last element in the array, say `x=50` in your example. You'll get an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException` as your `low` will increase and make the `mid` index out of bound.

I've corrected the aforementioned cases and the fixed function is like below:

```
static int findFloor(long[] arr, int n, long x) {
    if (x >= arr[arr.length - 1]) {
        return arr.length - 1;
    }
    int low = 0;
    int high = n - 1;
    while (low <= high) {
        int mid = (low + high) / 2;
        if (arr[mid] > x) {
            if (mid != 0 && arr[mid - 1] < x) {
                return mid;
            } else {
                high = mid - 1;
            }
        } else {
            if (arr[mid] == x || (mid != 0 && arr[mid + 1] > x)) {
                return mid;
            } else {
                low = mid + 1;
            }
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Hope you got your answer.